# unable to parse string to json in python

Tags: python, json, string

I have a string, which I evaluate as:

```
import ast
def parse(s):
    return ast.literal_eval(s)   


print parse(string)

 {'_meta': {'name': 'foo', 'version': 0.2},
     'clientId': 'google.com',
     'clip': False,
     'cts': 1444088114,
     'dev': 0,
     'uuid': '4375d784-809f-4243-886b-5dd2e6d2c3b7'}
```

But when I use jsonlint.com to validate the above json.. 
it throws schema error..

If I try to use json.loads
I see the following error:

```
Try: json.loads(str(parse(string)))
    ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1)
```

I am basically trying to convert this json in avro [How to covert json string to avro in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382636/how-to-covert-json-string-to-avro-in-python)

Comment: why not `json.loads(string)`?

Comment: Value error (posted in question  json.loads(str(parse(string)))
    ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 1 (char 1))

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it's not JSON, so `json.loads()` won't work.

Comment: `json.dumps(s)`, thought the output was what you wanted not what you were using

Comment: Yeah.. i had to do json.loads(json.dumps(s)) :)

Comment: @Fraz: but `string` **must** have been a string containing a Python literal, otherwise `ast.literal_eval()` would not have worked.. Using `json.dumps()` on that string produces a *JSON string* representing a string. `json.loads()` then produces the old string again, *not* a Python dictionary.

Comment: @Fraz: show us what `print repr(string)` is like. You probably want `print json.dumps(parse(string))` here, although you may want to avoid creating `string` in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval()` loads *Python syntax*. It won't parse JSON, that's what the `json.loads()` function is for.

Converting a Python object to a string with `str()` is still Python syntax, not JSON syntax, that is what `json.dumps()` is for.

JSON is not Python syntax. Python uses `None` where JSON uses `null`; Python uses `True` and `False` for booleans, JSON uses `true` and `false`. JSON strings always use `"` double quotes, Python uses either single or double, depending on the contents. When using Python 2, strings contain *bytes* unless you use `unicode` objects (recognisable by the `u` prefix on their literal notation), but JSON strings are fully Unicode aware. Python will use `\xhh` for Unicode characters in the Latin-1 range outside ASCII and `\Uhhhhhhhh` for non-BMP unicode points, but JSON only ever uses `\uhhhh` codes. JSON integers should generally be viewed as limited to the range representable by the C `double` type (since JavaScript numbers are always floating point numbers), Python integers have no limits other than what fits in your memory.

As such, JSON and Python syntax are not interchangeable. You cannot use `str()` on a Python object and expect to parse it as JSON. You cannot use `json.dumps()` and parse it with `ast.literal_eval()`. Don't confuse the two.