# Is it possible to generate Avro schma from JSON file?

Tags: json, avro

I have a JSON file. I'm looking for any program/tool which helps to generate AVRO schema based on that JSON file. I do not care about the data type. It can all be string as long as the AVRO schema structure is generated based on JSON.

The objective is, I'm trying to create a avro file using only json file. To do this, I would require avro schema.

so if I have an avro schema, using avro-tool, I'll be able to generate AVRO file by giving Avro schema and JSON file as input.

Any help/suggestions to proceed further will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to programmatically convert JSON to AVRO Schema?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556614/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-convert-json-to-avro-schema)

Comment: already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556614/is-there-a-way-to-programmatically-convert-json-to-avro-schema

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/romaanankin/avro-schema-manager

you can generate in from a simple .CSV. Just use the tool above