# Convert Json to Avro generic record python

Tags: python, json, avro

I have a problem statement to convert json to avro

Can you please provide me a reference where i need to convert json to avro genric record in my python program.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382636/how-to-covert-json-string-to-avro-in-python already answered here

Answer (score 0):

Can you give more insights to your question ?

the basic will be

```
import avro.schema
avro.schema.parse(json_str)
```

you can find everything here

http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.6/gettingstartedpython.html

Comment: I need to convert json string to avro genric record in python